# How to change the value of an input field with Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, field

After receiving a PO number just created from an Jquery ajax call $.ajax etc and when is success I capture the response.id_purchorder and I would like to asign it to a value of an imput field which  name and id is id_purchorder and it is not working.

this is part of my Form
echo "";
echo "Enviar";

this is the jquery code I am using to change the value of the input field from 1 to the real PO number coming from response.id_purchorder
$('input#idPurchorder').val(response.id_purchorder);  <--(NOT WORKING)
$('#texto_si_PO_fue_creada').html("Se ha creado el header de la PO: **" + response.id_purchorder + "**"); (this is working fine though)

[Jquery code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmC25.png)

Comment: `$('#idPurchorder')` is clearly not the same as `id="id_purchorder"`

Comment: sorry for that but it is just a mistake since I was trying to make it work so I tried having a different name for the name and id just in case. It is still not working. The original value = 1 remains

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. Since the form contains multiple rows ( items to purchase) maybe the id or name cannot repeat or jquery git confused because of that.
I have added a class with the name id_purchorder

```
echo "<input type='hidden' class = 'id_purchorder' name ='id_purchorder' id = 'id_purchorder' value='1'>";
```

and changed the jquery selection from ID to class

```
$('input.id_purchorder').val(response.id_purchorder);
```

It is working fine now. thanks